# Access menu-bar using keyboard on Mac OS X

Tags: key-bindings, osx, menu-bar

When I hit <kbd>C-f2</kbd> in any Mac OS X app (e.g., terminal, firefox), I get
keyboard access to the menu bar (file/edit/options &c)
In emacs I get a message `<C-f2> is undefined` in the Echo Area.
When I hit <kbd>f10</kbd> ([`menu-bar-open`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Menu-Bar.html)) in Emacs, get the 2 item menu `search with google` and
`add to itunes as a spoken track` or sometimes the single grayed-out item menu `select`.

- How do i get Emacs to pass <kbd>C-f2</kbd> to the OS?
- How do I get <kbd>f10</kbd> to invoke the real menu in Emacs?

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but wanted to mention an alternative method to popup the same type of menu using `mouse-popup-menubar`  Perhaps (with a little bit of a tweak) you could set that to a keyboard shortcut instead of the control right-click.  I use that instead of the main menu-bar, which I hide so that I get a little more screen real estate and a less distracting view when working.

Comment: And another option, which is not an answer, but may be useful:  `menu-bar-open`  It offers the same options as the menu-bar, but through the mini-buffer input.  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Menu-Bar.html

Comment: @lawlist: that's what `f10` already calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
(define-key global-map (kbd "C-<f2>")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (x-popup-menu (list '(0 0) (selected-frame))
                  (mouse-menu-bar-map))))
```

Also [fixed in the source tree](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=07efa3f0ba196c1eea130032c765d5d1a62fa627) so that now <kbd>f10</kbd> does the right thing.

This gives mouse-less access to the menu-bar *functionality*, not the OS menu *interface*, so the question of how to tell Emacs to pass certain keys to the OS remains open.

Comment: I'm seeing the the same behavior as `mouse-popup-menubar` with Emacs Trunk versions dated October and November 2014 on Snow Leopard 10.6.8.  The only difference is that the pop-up menu appears in the left-hand corner instead of wherever the mouse is.  This answer is not really the OSX equivalent of accessing the OSX menubar, which displays the Emacs menubar.

Comment: By way of example to explain my previous comment, `(global-set-key [C-down-mouse-3] 'mouse-popup-menubar)` will configure the same pop-up menu (as is used in this answer) for the key combination **Ctrl+Right-Click** -- the OSX menubar is not being used.

Comment: @lawlist: see edit

Comment: This is great. I actually mapped to *just* F2.

Comment: How could a real solution be achieved? Digging into emacs ObjC/Cocoa code?

Comment: @tomasorti: you might be able to find the code in the [Mac Port](http://www.math.s.chiba-u.ac.jp/~mituharu/emacs-mac.git)

Answer (score 0):

This does work for me with <kbd>Fn ^F2</kbd> (control function F2) using YAMAMOTO Mitsuharu's "[Emacs Mac Port](https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port)", installed via Homebrew.  More precisely, my current OS and emacs versions are

```
OS X 10.10.1 (14B25)
GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1343.14) of 2014-10-21 on iris-mac.crya.privado
```

The <kbd>Fn ^F2</kbd> shortcut is intercepted by the OS and never gets to Emacs.  It gives keyboard access to the menubar just as in other apps.  You have presumably turned on the option "Use all F1, F2, etc keys as standard function keys" in the Keyboard sheet of System Preferences, so you can just type <kbd>^F2</kbd> without using the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

Comment: Here: GNU Emacs 24.4.1 + Mac OS X 10.9.5 (13F34). It does not work :-(

Comment: Are you sure you are using the version of Emacs from https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port ?

Answer (score 0):

Without any configuration:

- **Ctrl-Alt-DownArrow**

this selects the apple icon in the menu-bar. From them, move left or right using the right/left keys.

This is for OSX 10.11.3 but maybe previous versions too? Please confirm!

- **Cmd-?**:

Out of the box, OS X 10.10 has the shortcut 'Cmd-?' (That is, 'Cmd-Shift-/') to access the Help menu of the menu bar.

This opens the menu Help and put the cursor in the text box in the 'Search Help' menu item.

From there, use the arrow keys to access other menus/menu items.

Comment: I get `C-? is undefined`

Comment: You're right, that is 'Cmd-?' not 'Ctrl-?' Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: `s-? runs the command info`

Comment: `<C-M-down> runs the command down-list`

Answer (score 0):

To use the menu bar on a Mac you use F10. This can be accomplished by pressing the Fn button on a MacBook Pro and then pressing F10.